# Python script does not update a variable

Tags: python, python-3.x, variables

I'm trying to make a Raspberry Pi (model B+) switch on a user chosen LED via GPIO by means of an `io.output()` function. However I have trouble getting my script to do so. The script is written in Python3.

```
# Set GPIO pins for each color
red = 11
yellow = 9
green = 10
# etc...

# LEDs are set as output
io.setup(red, io.OUT)
io.setup(yellow, io.OUT)
io.setup(green, io.OUT)
# etc...

# Function
def phase(color):
    io.output(color, io.HIGH)

color = input("Please choose a color like red, yellow, green, ...: ")
```

What I try to achieve is this: based on the choice the user makes, that particular LED is switched on.

The user has a choice of 10 colors.

I know this can be achieved by setting:

```
if color == 'red':
    io.output(red, io.HIGH)
elif color == 'yellow':
    io.output(yellow, io.HIGH)
elif color == 'green':
    io.output(green, io.HIGH)
#etc...
```

But I would like to only have 1 line of code in which the variable `color` is updated according to what color the user has chosen:

```
io.output(color, io.HIGH)
```

It seems that setting variables in Python3 works a little different then I thought (I'm used to PHP and not that experienced in Python3 yet).

I would expect the variable `color` to be processed by Python into the users input (let's say "red"), which should subsequently by processed into the corresponding GPIO pin number which is `11`.

However that doesn't take place and I can't figure out why. I keep getting errors telling me that `color` should be an integer. And I thought variables in this case worked like `color = red = 11`.

How do I pass a variable in my `io.output()` function? Is that possible or am I stuck with having to write a line of code for each color LED? That seems very redundant to me but maybe I'm completely wrong here.

Comment: you can create dictionary `{"red": 11, ...}` to convert it and then you can use it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your variable `color` contains a string. You appear to want some way to map that string to an integer. A [dictionary](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries) (`dict`) would be perfect for that and allow some other optimizations as well:

```
# Set GPIO pins for each color
colors = {
    'red': 11,
    'yellow': 9,
    'green': 10,
    # etc...
}

# LEDs are set as output
[io.setup(v, io.OUT) for k,v in colors]

# Function
def phase(color):
    io.output(colors[color], io.HIGH)

color = input("Please choose red, yellow or green: ")
phase(color)
```

Comment: Thank you! Can't believe I missed the whole string vs. var thing.. Your code worked a treat but had to be slightly improved for it to be flawless in Python3: `[io.setup(v, io.OUT) for k,v in colors.items()]`

Answer (score 1):

You can use dictionary to convert string to integer

```
all_colors = {
    "red": 11,
    "yellow": 9,
    "green": 10
}

color = input("Please choose a color like red, yellow, green, ...: ")
color = color.lower().strip()

if color in all_colors:
    value = all_colors[color]
    io.output( value, io.HIGH )
else:
    print("unknown color")
```

Comment: An elegant solution as well! I redesigned my input check with your code.